# Populating a Dictionary with LINQ to XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml, linq-to-objects

I am using LINQ to XML to parse an XML document and create a number of objects from that XML. One of the objects has a Dictionary as a property and I need to populate the Dictionary from the XML. However, I am unsure of the actual syntax required to do so.

I know that I need to get the attribute values and somehow assign them to the key/value in the dictionary.

How do I do this?

I have a model class like this:

```
public class Statistics
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<string, string> Information { get; set; }
}
```

And XML like this:

```
  <section>
    <parameter name="this is a key" value="this is a value" />
    <parameter name="this is a key 2" value="this is a value 2" />
  </section>
```

In my LINQ query I need to set the key and value from the `name` and `value` attributes.

From my understanding I need to do something along the lines of:

```
.ToDictionary(x => x.name, x => x.value);
```

But I am unsure how to apply that to my LINQ query, the following code is a part of a larger LINQ to XML query:

```
.Select(x => new Statistics
                {
                    Name = x.Attribute("name").Value,
                    Information = What goes here? .Select.Attributes? .ToDictionary(x => x.name, x => x.value);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var dict = XDocument.Load(filename)
           .Descendants("parameter")
           .ToDictionary(p => p.Attribute("name").Value, p => p.Attribute("value").Value);
```

Comment: The only problem with this is that I've already called XDocument.Load. Is there another way without loading it twice?

Comment: @user9993 `XDocument.Load(filename)` returns `XElement` . So You can use any appropriate XElement like `p.Descendants("parameter").ToDictionary(.....)`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's the best solution.

I would do something like that :

```
.Select(x => new Statistics
            {
                Name = x.Attribute("name").Value,
                Information = GetParameterDictionnary(sectionNode)
```

and I would create the function

```
private Dictionary<string, string> GetParameterDictionnary(XmlNode sectionNode)
{
    var dictionary = new Dictionary<string,string>();
    foreach(var child in sectionNode.Children)
    {
        dictionary.Add(child.Attribute("name"), child.Attribute("value"));
    }
    return dictionary;
}
```

Comment: How would I get the sectionNode from within the query?

Comment: The other answer seems to answer the problem better than my partial solution (wich rely on partial example)